# Memory Management problems with new Dell XPS Laptop

Tags: laptop, windows-8.1, memory, bsod, dell-xps

I recently bought the latest and "best" Dell XPS 15 with preinstalled Windows 8.1. In the two weeks I am using it now, there have been a lot of application crashes, unexpected system shutdowns and also some BSODs.

- In Chrome some websites crash frequently
- A lot of java programs (e.g. eclipse) often fail to start with EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) / Problematic frame: jvm.dll+0x42b896 for example
- BSOD always show the problem MEMORY_MANAGEMENT, mostly in ntoskrnl.exe

Then, sometimes I can work for hours without any visible problems...

What I already tried/did:
I am using the latest drivers provided by Dell, did a system checkup (HDD, Memory) using Dell and Windows tools - without any clue. System fans are off or low, so I wouldn't guess it's a thermal problem.

Comment: Send it back. Don't waste your time, it should be working out of the box. Even if you do fix it now, it *could* lead into continued intermittent issues in the future. Sounds like the RAM is either faulty or not seated. This is easy to ensure, take the panel off the back and ensure it is seated well, either way, as I said, if it was me, I'd send it back.

Comment: In fact, Dell diagnostics tool that runs outside Windows reported "Memory issues have been resolved". Memtest86 also found problems. I will see if it works now..

Answer (score 0):

Although both DELL checkup utitlites didn't find memory problems any more, a short test with memtest86 revealed a lot of problems. After exchanging RAM in one slot, the memory errors were gone and I believe that all of the problems described above will not occur any more.